# Enum helper in c# not giving expected result

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, enums

Basically I am not recieving the correct enum type for some reason and I cannot figure out why, my code is below, many thanks in advance for any pointers/ explanation...

EDIT: type-> changed to anothername (thanks guys for the heads up)

Helper:

```
 public static T Convert<T>(this string str)
    {
        return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), str, true);
    }
```

Enum values:

```
public enum anothername
    {
        SmallText = 100,
        Number = 15,
        TextArea = 0,
        Bool = 0,
        Choices = 0,
    }
```

My test:

```
 [Test]
        public void EnumGetStringFromEnumType()
        {
            //arrange
            var MaxLength = EnumHelper.Convert<anothername>("TextArea").ToString();

            //act

            //assert
            Assert.AreEqual("TextArea", MaxLength);


        }
```

EDIT:

Thanks, removing the int values solved it!

However... what if I actually wanted to have say values for some enum types and not other e.g.

```
public enum anothername
    {
        SmallText = 100,
        Number = 15,
        TextArea,
        Bool,
        Choices,
    }
```

Test 2:

```
[Test]
        public void EnumGetIntValueOrStringFromEnumType()
        {
            //arrange
            var MaxLength = EnumHelper.ToEnumSafe<anothername>("TextArea");

            //act

            //assert
            Assert.AreEqual(null, (int)MaxLength);

        }
```

I have exactly the same problem when I try and retrieve the int values, I get incorrect results...
result = 16

Comment: 1) you might want to use a different name than "Type" to avoid confusion; 2) your assert checks a string against your enum, typo?; 3) there is no difference between TextArea, Bool and Choices as they all have an underlying value of 0.

Comment: Is there a reason the last three Types have the same value? Enums should have different values.

Comment: It's probably a bad idea to use the name Type for your enum, as that conflicts with System.Type. Maybe try changing that to MyType and see if it works as expected.

Comment: sorry... I just renamed it whilst I was posting! Lack of imagination... thanks for the heads up anyway, the reason why I have the same value is because I am trying to get the enum type and if the type is one where I do not check for length validation I use 0 in its place, looks like it was a very bad idea!

Comment: By the way `Type` is a bit of a confusing name for the `enum` in that test.

Comment: @ Hans my test checks a string yes, but that is not the problem, I removed the 0's and it works!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The enumeration has duplicate members with the same underlying value as `TextArea` (`Bool` and `Choices`). Although the parse should succeed, the value of `ToString` on the resulting enum instance is not defined, and may not equal "TextArea" as your assertion is expecting.

From the 
[**`Enum.ToString`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0h36syw.aspx) documentation:

> If multiple enumeration members have
>   the same underlying value and you
>   attempt to retrieve the string
>   representation of an enumeration
>   member's name based on its underlying
>   value, your code should not make any
>   assumptions about which name the
>   method will return.

**EDIT**:

In response to your edit, try this assertion:

```
var MaxLength = EnumHelper.ToEnumSafe<anothername>("TextArea");
Assert.AreEqual(anotherName.TextArea, MaxLength);
```

or if you prefer comparing the underlying type:

```
Assert.AreEqual((int)anotherName.TextArea, (int)MaxLength);
```

You appear to be under the impression that an enum member is not associated with an underlying value if its value is not *explicitly* specified. This is not the case; *all* members of an enum are associated with an underlying value. The rules for the 'implicit' associations are given by (from the [language specification](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=DFBF523C-F98C-4804-AFBD-459E846B268E)):

> • If the enum member is the first enum
>   member declared in the enum type, its
>   associated value is zero.
>
> •  Otherwise,
>   the associated value of the enum
>   member is obtained by increasing the
>   associated value of the textually
>   preceding enum member by one. This
>   increased value must be within the
>   range of values that can be
>   represented by the underlying type,
>   otherwise a compile-time error occurs.

Comment: This is what is happening.  The EnumHelper.Convert returns TextArea, but the ToString returns Choices.

Comment: @Ani -> How would I handle the case where an enum has a value, and where an enum does not have a value? Should I still use Enum?

Comment: Are you looking for [nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s(v=VS.100).aspx) enums? You could of course use a normal enum and have an 'Undefined' member. Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: As described above, if I do not declare some enum types, I seem to get inconsistent results... I will edit once more to show the example...